# Take input from text box and parse each line into bullet list

Tags: php, parsing

```
$method1 = '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', explode("\n", $method)) . '</li></ul>';
```

I have this code here and i am trying to parse the input so that each new line that is entered into a text box is parsed to a bullet list, but for some reason this code is only doing the first line

Example:

```
do this
do this
```

turns into this inside a single variable:

```
<ul>
<li>do this</li>
<li>do this</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Is that html sample what it SHOULD be, or what you're getting? Because if it's what you're getting, the code would be working as expected...

Comment: @Tomalak Ok so the text in the text box has no html bullet list point formatting only carriage returns. How would i parse the text in the text box so that each new line will be <li>foo</li> and the whole string will be encased in <ul></ul>

Comment: @Marc B No that example is what i want it to do inside a single php variable.

Comment: why not using a wysiwyg editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this (I've used your variable names):

```
// explode
$list = explode("\n", $method);

// iterate
$method1 = "<ul>";
foreach ($list as $item) {
  $method1 .= "<li>" . $item . "</li>";
}
$method1 .= "</ul>";

// output
echo $method1;
```

Comment: Kinda, but it isnt putting a <li></li> on each new line only the whole variable.

Answer (score 0):

Somethimes **\n** doesnt really recognize as new line in php.

try this:

```
$method1 = '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', explode("
", $method)) . '</li></ul>';
```